# Optimal solution to find the leafs of a tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, tree-search

I have a tree-like structure. I can get several lines that connect together and make up the tree. The lines are made up start-points and end-points. here is some sample data from a tree in XML format.

```
<Skeleton>
   <Line StartX="384" StartY="135"  EndX="385" EndY="129"  /> 
   <Line StartX="384" StartY="137"  EndX="384" EndY="135"  /> 
   <Line StartX="384" StartY="138"  EndX="384" EndY="137"  /> 
   <Line StartX="384" StartY="139"  EndX="384" EndY="138"  /> 
   <Line StartX="383" StartY="144"  EndX="384" EndY="139"  /> 
   <Line StartX="383" StartY="147"  EndX="383" EndY="144"  /> 
    ...
</Skeleton>
```

and here is a graphical representation of the tree:

[image]

What I need to do is to extract the leafs and the junctions on this tree as it is shown in the image:
[image]

I want to find an optimized algorithm regarding complexity and time to do this task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for algorithm: skeleton generation for raster images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060540/looking-for-algorithm-skeleton-generation-for-raster-images)

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate, that post wants to get the skeleton out of an image. different stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Generate a mathematical graph out of your data (coordinates are the labels of the vertices and each `line` from your data becomes an edge in the graph).
2. define the `root vertex` of your tree.
3. **leafs** are all vertices that are not the `root vertex` and connected to only one edge
4. **junctions** are all vertices that are connected to at least 3 edges (in your example)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. therefore, after having the graph, I can use some search algorithms to find the leafs.

Comment: Why not simply create a tree and do level order traversal and traverse all nodes except root node? Why take complicated root of graph(Though tree is also a graph)

Comment: @AKS: As you mentioned yourself _'tree is also a graph'_. I cannot see, why you think using a graph is more complicated than using a tree. By the way, how would you create the tree while parsing the XML? While parsing the XML the already parsed will most likely not be a tree most of the times, because we cannot make any assumptions about the order of the lines in the XML.